# CSS: Equal margins on inside and outside of elements

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have two 6 column images in a bootstrap row. I would like the margin between the two elements to be the same as the margin between the outside of the images and the parent.

I have tried adding margins/padding to the images, but applying it to the left and right sides of the images causes the gap in the middle to be double.

[Image indicating setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tjEzB.png)

Comment: You have to share your code

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, Bootstrap adds a certain amount of padding (15px) to both the left and right sides of every one of your grid column. So, in your screenshot, the middle red area has a total width of 30px, resulting from the right padding of your first grid column and the left padding of your second grid column.

You can write custom css to target the non-first child grid column and set their left padding to 7.5px, and target the non-last child grid column and set their right padding to 7.5px.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script
      src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script
      src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <style>
      .bg-red {
        background-color: red;
      }

      .fake-img {
        background-color: green;
        height: 500px;
      }

      .custom-col:not(:last-child) {
        padding-right: 7.5px;
      }

      .custom-col:not(:first-child) {
        padding-left: 7.5px;
      }
    </style>

    <title>Bootstrap Example Page</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6 bg-red custom-col">
          <div class="fake-img">
            img 1
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6 bg-red custom-col">
          <div class="fake-img">
            img 2
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```